# Ｗhat does a noun + に mean? How does the particle に work here?

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-に, nouns, sentence

I found the next sentence:

```
魔物が防御に徹するかのように動く。
```

And when I searched the word 防御 I found out that this word works only as a noun and as a のadjective, hence my doubt regarding the use and meaning of に in this particular sentence.

My question is, is it working with a "aim" meaning? or is it working with a "-ly meaning (like
"defensively" or something like that)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your title question, noun+に has no special meaning at all. You should think of this に as working with the verb 徹する. This verb means "devote oneself **to**". The thing you are devoting yourself **to** is marked with に.

> 魔物が防御に徹するかのように動く。
> The monster moves as though devoting itself **to** defense.